# Unable to create SQL lite database using a docker-compose command

Tags: sqlite, docker-compose

The following docker-compose file is a combination of the default template from docker and my additions. I'm trying to, when executing `docker-compose up`, create a default database (mydb.db in this example).

```
version: '3'

services:
  sqlite3:
    image: nouchka/sqlite3:latest
    container_name: sqlite
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
    entrypoint: /usr/bin/sqlite3
    command:
      - /usr/bin/sqlite3 mydb.db;
    volumes:
      - ./db/:/root/db/
```

However, no database is being created. If I manually enter the container `docker exec -it sqlite bash` and type `sqlite3 mydb.db;`, it behaves as expected.

Am I understanding what `command` does incorrectly? I'm not an expert at docker by any stretch.